# F# Powerpack's Metadata doesn't recognize FSharp.Core as an F# library

Tags: f#, metadata, powerpack

Here's my test code to isolate the problem:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
  let core = FSharpAssembly.FromFile @"C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\\bin\FSharp.Core.dll"
  let core2 = FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary
  let core3 = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() 
              |> Seq.find (fun a -> a.FullName.Contains "Core") 
              |> FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly

  core.Entities |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
  0
```

All three `let`s should give me the same FSharpAssembly. Instead, all 3 throw an exception that FSharp.Core is not an F# assembly (details below, re-formatted for readability). Two more clues:

1. Using the `core3` method, I get the same error for the test F# assembly itself
2. I don't get the error at FSI after doing `#r "@C:\Program Files...\FSharp.Powerpack.Metadata.dll"`.

Any ideas? I'm using Visual Studio 2008, F# 2.0 and F# Powerpack 2.0.0.0 (May 20, 2010) release on an oldish XP VM, I think it's updated to SP3 though.

(I got the error this morning with Powerpack 1.9.9.9, so I upgraded to 2.0.0.0. I thought that if 1.9.9.9 doesn't recognise F#'s 2.0.0.0's assemblies, then maybe bugfixes in Powerpack 2.0.0.0 would help.)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 
  The type initializer for 'Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.AssemblyLoader' threw an
    exception. 
  ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
    '<StartupCode$FSharp-PowerPack-Metadata>.$Metadata' threw an exception. 
  ---> System.ArgumentException: could not produce an FSharpAssembly 
    object for the assembly 'FSharp.Core' because 
    this is not an F# assembly
Parameter name: name
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.AssemblyLoader.Add(String name,Assembly assembly)
   at <StartupCode$FSharp-PowerPack-Metadata>.$Metadata..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.AssemblyLoader..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.AssemblyLoader.Get(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata.FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at Program.main(String[] args) in 
     C:\Documents an...\FSMetadataTest\Program.fs:line 11
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nathan, great investigation, the version number was indeed not updated in original May2010 release, see http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/workitem/4548
We have uploaded binaries with corrected version number.

Answer (score 3):

I found the immediate cause of the problem by reading the [Powerpack source on Codeplex](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/46549#). Powerpack.Metadata always loads FSharp.Core before any other assembly, so if it's broken, it blocks the rest.

From my research, most other F# assemblies carry their metadata with them in a manifest resource stream named "FSharpSignatureData.*Package.Name*"--that's where the Metadata library looks first. But FSharp.Core doesn't. (At least, on my XP VM the 2.0.0.0 download for VS 2008 does not.) So the Powerpack Metadata looks for a file called FSharp.Core.sigdata in the same directory it expects to find FSharp.Core.dll.

The code looks four places for this directory name:

1. ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.["fsharp-core-referenceassembly-location"].
2. The registry key `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\" + MSCorLibRunningRuntimeVersion + @"\AssemblyFoldersEx\Microsoft Visual F# 4.0"`, where MSCorLibRunningRuntimeVersion is determined by reflection--in my case it's "v2.0.50727". I think this only applies if you have VS 2010 and hence F# 4.0
3. The registry key `@"Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\Microsoft.FSharp-" + FSharpTeamVersionNumber`, where FSharpTeamVersionNumber is *hard-coded* as "1.9.9.9", at least in the codeplex version. I don't have the source for the May 2010 release installed on my machine.
4. System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. This is the "bin/Debug" directory of your local project, *unless* you are in fsi. Then it's some variant of C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin.

For me, all four fail:

1. I don't have an app config file. I don't know the .NET ecosystem very well, so I don't know how to create one.
2. I don't have VS 2010 installed.
3. I have a "Microsoft.FSharp-2.0.0.0" key in the right place, but no "Microsoft.FSharp-1.9.9.9" key.
4. My local project doesn't have a copy of FSharp.Core.sigdata in the bin/Debug directory.

Now that I know what's going on, I have a number of fixes (besides using a real Windows machine instead of an ancient VM, which I plan to fix in about a month). I should *probably* learn about .NET's config files at some point anyway, so that's probably the best medium-term solution. Creating the registry key "Microsoft.FSharp-1.9.9.9" or copying FSharp.Core.sigdata to the bin/Debug directory is a super easy short-term fix.

I still don't know if this bug should be widespread or if it's just caused by my upgrades from VS 2005->2008 and multiple F# previews. From reading the codeplex source, it seems to me that other people without VS 2010 should also have this problem, just because FSharpTeamVersionNumber is hard-coded as 1.9.9.9, and hasn't been updated to match the registry key, 2.0.0.0. But maybe the order that I upgraded to F# 2.0 and the F# Powerpack 2.0 was incorrectly intermingled to produce this condition. Or maybe there aren't enough people using the Metadata library to expose the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is really confusing - I tried running the code using the exact scenario you described (F# 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008, with the latest PowerPack 2.0 from CodePlex) and it works without any exceptions.

You could also make sure that you have the latest release of F# for Visual Studio 2008 (that was released shortly after final version of Visual Studio 2010), because `FSharp.Core.dll` that you're loading needs to be compatible with `FSharp.PowerPack.Metadata.dll`. Also, is the `Metadata` library able to load other `dll` libraries that you compile with the current version of F# compiler?

**EDIT**
If this doesn't work then (I'd think) the `Metadata` library is probably out of sync with the F# compiler:

```
let a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
     |> FSharpAssembly.FromAssembly
printf "%A" a.Entities.Count
```

If the following doesn't work then that would be *really confusing* - no matter what version, the library should be able to read itself!

```
let a = FSharpAssembly.FromFile @"C:\...\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.Metadata.dll"
printf "%A" a.Entities.Count
```

Comment: To answer your last question: no. Not when I try `FromAssembly` on the currently loaded assembly, at least. I will check for a newer version of F#.

Comment: @Nathan: You could also try whether the `Metadata` library is able to read itself - I'd think that this should work.

Comment: Good point. I will check that too. I re-installed F#, didn't make a difference, so I am running Windows update, getting SP2 of .NET 2.0 and 3.0. Not that I expect it to help, but who knows.

Comment: Well, this is annoying: both of your snippets fail when `Metadata` attempts to load an FSharpAssembly for `FSharp.Core`. So apparently you can't avoid loading `FSharp.Core`, even when you request to load something else.

Comment: @Nathan: Yeah, I guess that `FSharp.Core` is loaded in the initializer of the module (so it is loaded eagerly when you access anything from `Metadata`). That's a bit unfortunate, but probably needed...