# F# 2.0 with Powerpack 2.0, fslex error 1

Tags: f#, compiler-errors, powerpacks, fsyacc, fslex

In namespace RSLispV3.RunTime:
http://pastebin.com/XNb9qi11

LispParser.fsy:
http://pastebin.com/pymF1Vvm

LispLexer.fsl:
http://pastebin.com/pfXdDuxs

I got in MSBuild the PowerPacks targets, calling them from the .fsprog.

When building with VS2008 I get error: "fslex.exe" exited with code 1.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: my mistake, no ^ operator. Line 11 for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same bug I ran into with [the Powerpack Metadata library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921880/f-powerpacks-metadata-doesnt-recognize-fsharp-core-as-an-f-library).

You can test it by temporarily creating the registry key

```
Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\Microsoft.FSharp-1.9.9.9
```

(an equivalent with 2.0.0.0 should already be there.)

Or just download the updated powerpack binaries; they fixed the problem a couple of days ago.

Comment: What updated binaries? I downloaded the Powerpack 10 hours ago - latest version 2.0.0.0.